# Add New Look up field in new Custom object which is related to Email Template in Salesforce

Tags: salesforce

How to add new Look up field in my custom object which should be related to Email Template object in salesforce.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot create a lookup to the `EmailTemplate` object, but you can provide similar functionality by storing the template Id as text (but this would require a VF page and custom controller to provide the user a method of selecting the template). I'm curious though, what exactly is the use case for associating an email template to a record?

Comment: JCD is correct, the only way to do this would be save some unique reference to the `EmailTemplate` record in a text field (either it's Id or DeveloperName). As to use cases, JCD, I can think of several. One would be in creating a Survey app where you want to have a custom EmailTemplate per Survey record to use when alerting survey recipients that the survey is active for response. To store such a linkage between a Survey and its EmailTemplate, it would be helpful to store an EmailTemplate reference in a lookup field on Survey.

Comment: I have the same use-case, we want users to select/create missing email templates that will later be used by the automated email system. The events for this customisation are independent (i.e. not like a theatre), thus have independent email templates.